# Setting default debug commandline arguments by code?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, arguments, command-line-arguments

There is a way to set the default debug commandline arguments or the default application arguments without setting the arguments in the Debug tab of the project settings?

I'll mean if I can do something like this:

```
Module Main

#If DEBUG Then
  ' Debug Commandline arguments for my application:
  My.Application.CommandLineArgs = "-Sleep 5 -Interval 50 -Key CTRL+C"
#End If

...Sub main()
   GetArguments() ' A function wich gets the arguemnts that I've set.
...etc...

End module
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a class that will abstract your other code from command line. For debug compilation it will return fixed string, otherwise it will return real Enviroment.CommandLine.

```
public static class CommandLineHelper
{
  public static string GetCommandLine()
  {
   #if DEBUG
     return "my command line string";
   #else
     return Enviroment.CommandLine;
   #endif
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I've any idea of how to do that, can you give me a reference of MSDN or something to me to start trying it?

Comment: I've added basic C# sample, you can try converting it to VB, if it is needed.

Comment: Thankyou now I understanded what you said me.